# PHP FORM UPLOAD

Tags: php

it returns content uploaded successfully but no image is displayed. what can i do to fix this problem or move uploaded file stream not found. how can i do this correctly. please help.thanks
     MY code;

```
<?php include('includes/connect.php'); ?>
<?php include('includes/function.php'); ?>
<?php
if($_POST['add']){
            $h1  = trim($_POST['heading']);
            $t1  = trim($_POST['text']);
            $sql = "INSERT INTO home ( heading,text)VALUES('{$h1}', '{$t1}')" ;

            //die(print($sql));
            $result = mysql_query($sql); 
            confirm_query($result);


        if($_FILES['photo']['name'])
{
    //if no errors...
    if(!$_FILES['photo']['error'])
    {
        //now is the time to modify the future file name and validate the file
        $new_file_name = strtolower($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']); //rename file
        if($_FILES['photo']['size'] > (1024000)) //can't be larger than 1 MB
        {
            $valid_file = false;
        }
        if($valid_file)
        {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/'.$new_file_name);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //set that to be the returned message
        $msg = 'Ooops!  Your upload triggered the following error:  '.$_FILES['photo']['error'];
        header("Location:home_add.php?msg=$msg");
        exit;
    }
}

            //die(printf($sql));
            if($result){
                $msg="Content uploaded Successfully!";
                //$_SESSION['loggein_msg'] = 'Content updated Successfully!';
                header("Location:home_add.php?msg=$msg");
                exit;

            }else{
                $msg= "Content upload failed!";
                header("Location:home_add.php?msg=$msg");
            }
        }
?>      
?>
```

it returns content uploaded successfully but no image is displayed

Comment: does your `<form>` tag have `enctype='multipart/form-data'`? Does the file get actually uploaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure your form has `enctype='multipart/form-data'`

```
<form enctype='multipart/form-data' ..... >
```

And then

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/'.$_FILES['photo']['name']);
```

Make sure the form upload field has the same name is `photo`

Answer (score 0):

`move_uploaded_file` 2nd parameter should be a proper path to the image, you shouldn't use `tmp_name` for the same. Hence, replace this line :

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/'.$new_file_name);
```

to :

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/'.$_FILES['photo']['name']);
```

to keep the original file name in server, else change the file name as per your requirement with same extension.

Answer (score 0):

**Change this.**

```
$new_file_name = strtolower($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']);
```

**To this.**

```
$new_file_name = strtolower($_FILES['photo']['name']);
```

**It's Done.**